# Witten's QFT Jones polynomial work on Atiyah Patodi Singer theorem and $\hat A$ genus over Chern character

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology, quantum-field-theory, index-theory

In Witten's 1989 QFT and Jones polynomial paper,

he wrote in eq.2.22 that

> Atiyah Patodi Singer theorem says that the combination:
> $$
> \frac{1}{2} \eta_{grav} + \frac{1}{12}\frac{I(g)}{2 \pi}
> $$
> is a topological invariant, depending that is on the oriented three manifold M with a choice of trivialization of the tangent bundle, but not on the metric of M.

But then he quoted in footnote 4:

> The crucial factor of 1/12 in (2.22) reflects the discrepancy between the Chern character $$e^x = 1 + x^2/2 + ...$$ that appears in gauge theory index theorems and the $\hat A$ genus
> $$(x/2)/sinh(x/2) = 1 -x^2/24 + ...$$
> that appears in gravitational index theorems

I am puzzled:

1. Is that equation wrong there $e^x = 1 + x^2/2 + ...$? Should it be $e^x = 1 + x + x^2/2 + ...$ or do I miss something?
2. Why the ratio of $x^2$ coefficient for $\hat A$ genus over Chern character has something to do with the $(1/24)/(1/2)=1/12$ appeared in the Atiyah Patodi Singer theorem's $1/12$? What is the intuitive understanding here?

Please give some pedagogical statement if possible. I appreciate your feedback and answer.

p.s. Witten's footnote:

[image]

Comment: He considers compact simple Lie groups so the first Chern class vanishes.